# Change variable in included jinja2 template

Tags: jinja2

Say I have two templates:

**main.j2**

```
{% include "vars.j2" %}

main: {{ var1 }}
```

**vars.j2**

```
{% set var1 = 123 %}

vars: {{ var1 }}
```

When run, only this line is output:

```
vars: 123
```

i.e. `var1` is undefined in `main.j2`, even though it gets set to a value in the included `vars.j2` template.

How can I pass variables from included template back to template that includes it? I considered chaining extends, but wondered if there's a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a need to do the same thing, and found 2 solutions.

If you have Jinja version 2.10 or later, namespaces can be used:

**main_ns.j2**:

```
{% set ns = namespace() %}
{% include "vars_ns.j2" %}
main_ns: {{ ns.var1 }}
```

**vars_ns.j2**:

```
{% set ns.var1 = 123 %}
vars_ns: {{ ns.var1 }}
```

In Jinja 2.2 or later, it can be accomplished with block scoping of variables. I put the variable settings in the base template so that multiple children can extend it.

**vars_block.j2**:

```
{% set var1 = 123 %}
vars_block: {{ var1 }}
{% block content scoped %}{% endblock %}
```

**main_block.j2**:

```
{% extends "vars_block.j2" %}
{% block content %}
main_block: {{ var1 }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `with`:

```
{% with var1=0 %}
    {% include "vars.j2" %}
    vars: {{ var1 }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks @jrbedard. On my end, doing this produces `main: 0` instead of `main: 123`.